# Unable to launch third party software via command line from Shiny app hosted on AWS EC2

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, shiny, command-line, shiny-server

I am in the process of creating a Shiny app, which reads in Excel files, renames them and then converts them into PDF files. The conversion step is performed by LibreOffice at the command line with:

```
libreoffice --convert-to pdf myfile.xlsx
```

Since I needed LibreOffice as an external dependency for my project, I could not use shinyapps.io since there is no straightforward way to install LibreOffice on there. Therefore, I resorted to launching an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance and installed LibreOffice's latest version. Of course, I also installed Shiny Server so my app could be hosted on there. I need to mention that I am a beginner at using Shiny server on an AWS EC2 instance and using the Unix command line overall.

Now, here is my issue. When I connect to the server via ssh and use LibreOffice to convert some Excel files to PDF, it works perfectly. However, when I try to access LibreOffice via the launched Shiny app via command line functions, it seems that the app does not have access to the software. I verified whether Shiny realizes that LibreOffice is installed on the server with:

```
which libreoffice
```

and it does since the response is

```
/usr/bin/libreoffice
```

But it appears as though Shiny is unable to use it for some reason. The error message I get even when I try to determine LibreOffice's version from Shiny with

```
libreoffice --version
```

is

```
Executing 'libreoffice' failed with status 127
```

which means that the `libreoffice` command was not found according to my research. Once again, when I'm on the server using the command line, everything works perfectly.

It baffles me how Shiny knows that the software is installed, but cannot use it. I even verified the permissions on `libreoffice` from Shiny with

```
ls -l -H /usr/bin/libreoffice
```

and obtained

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6731 Mar  1 08:39 /usr/bin/libreoffice
```

I am no expert in Unix/Linux, but I think that this means that all users have access to it?

My question, then, is: **How do I get Shiny to use third party software installed on a server?**

It may also be important to mention that I use the [wonderful sys package by Jeroen Ooms](https://github.com/jeroen/sys) for all my command line needs instead of using `system2()` in base R.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the exact R command you are running? Maybe there is a problem with the syntax.

Comment: @MrFlick This is unlikely as I ran other commands with the same syntax. First, I run: `res <- exec_internal(cmd = "libreoffice", args = "--version")`. Then, I display the output in a `shiny::verbatimTextOutput` with `as_text(res$stdout)`. I used this syntax to test other base CLI tools such as `which` or `whomami` and it worked.

Comment: Does `Sys.which("libreoffice")` within R/shiny return the `/usr/bin/libreoffice` path?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes indeed, I just tried it at your request and even R returns the same path: `/usr/bin/libreoffice`.

Comment: @MrFlick After doing a bit more research and asking questions, I found out that it turns out that Shiny server's user is `shiny` and that this user does not have a privileged access on the system. This is why a Shiny app cannot run system commands. I am now researching how to give Shiny server some higher privileges.

Comment: This seems tricky: while trying to replicate this in a Docker container, I get an error running `system2("libreoffice", "--version")` from R even as `root` -- but the same command works from outside R on the command line directly. Using `sudo` with the command from R seems to fix it, but of course that may not be an option for the user that Shiny runs as.

Comment: I can succesfully run the command from R if I set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable for the R process, [as described here](https://codeyarns.com/tech/2019-09-05-libregloso-cannot-open-shared-object-file.html). Maybe that could help you, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this in a Docker container, which may or may not lead to the same error. The error I was getting was a "missing file", even when executed as from an R process launched as `root`.

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Following [this advice](https://codeyarns.com/tech/2019-09-05-libregloso-cannot-open-shared-object-file.html) and setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable fixed the issue in my testing.
I could succesfully run `libreoffice --version` from Shiny when testing with this app:

```r
library(shiny)

Sys.setenv(
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/usr/lib/libreoffice/program:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("command", "Enter a command"),
  submitButton("Submit"),
  verbatimTextOutput("output"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$output <- renderPrint({
    system(input$command, intern = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8080))
```

And, for completeness, the `Dockerfile` I tested with:

```
FROM rocker/shiny

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  libreoffice-common

COPY . .

CMD ["Rscript", "app.R"]
```

And command to run the image:

```sh
docker run --user shiny --rm -it -p 8080:8080 shiny-libre
```

Comment: I've just tested also with `sys::exec_internal()`, which does give me the same `status 127` -- probably the same issue, and hopefully the same solution, then.

Comment: I just incorporated the environment variable to the app and it works. I am also still using `sys::exec_internal()`. I am not quite sure why it did not work on your end.